# Tapestry: invoking eventLink issue

Tags: resources, tapestry

I have a form and when I press on submit, should open a PDF. When I do it first time it works, but no next times.

My code:

```
Object onDoPDF() {  

        return new PDFStreamResponse
                    (pdfGenerator.generatePDF("doPDF");
    }

    Object onSuccessFromMyForm() {
        return resources.createEventLink("doPDF");  
    }
```

Next times, onSuccess is invoked not onDoPDF() method

Comment: Have you checked what is happening in the browser, i.e. the request sent and response returned, and whether the PDF is requested at all the second time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this way?

```
Object onSuccessFromMyForm() {
    return new PDFStreamResponse
                (pdfGenerator.generatePDF("doPDF");
}
```